# How to use GRUB from a USB drive to boot any OS that is on the HDD?

Tags: boot, windows, grub

I got two operating systems on my laptop(Win 8.1 and Kali), but i updated from win 7 and deleted the boot record. To be honest i don't want Grub on my HDD, i like booting directly into windows. My idea was to install Grub on to a usb stick and load into kali whenever i need to or want to. Is that possible? I only found topics on booting all kind of OS's from usb but not from HDD.

Comment: Yes. This is possible. You just need to create a `ext4` partition in your USB drive and then boot into some live distro and install grub into the newly created partition of your USB drive. Try following this tutorial: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: @shivams thx, i will get a new usb stick, try it out and report back

Comment: @shivams I used a different method than suggested. Installing grub worked, but grub alone on the stick couldn't do anything(grub rescue).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the best method for me to start Kali without reinstalling Grub to my HDD. For this i used unetbootin and SuperGrub([Download here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/))

- First install unetbootin:

> sudo apt-get install unetbootin

- Then rename the supergrub .iso to .img (using .iso gave me booterrors) and start unetbootin.
- In unetbootin select the floppy method and load the renamed .img file.
- Select the USB drive and press OK.
- Now use the stick to boot whatever OS is on your HDD.

I used the USB stick on my laptop and loaded into Supergrub and found every OS that is installed on the HDD. Worked great. This way i can keep windows as main OS and always boot directly into it and whenever i want to use Kali i just pop in my USB drive and use Supergrub.